# How to load values into extern shared array

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu-shared-memory

When loading arrays from global memory to shared memory, variables in shared memory are not doing what I want.

```
template<class T>
__global__ void kernel(T *t1,T *t2)
{
     int tid=threadIdx.x;
     extern __shared__ T array1[];
     extern __shared__ T array2[];
     array1[tid]=t1[tid];//copy (1)
     array2[tid]=t2[tid];//copy (2)
     __syncthreads();
}
```

Things turn out that `array1[tid]`=`array2[tid]`=`t2[tid]`.

when exchange the place of `copy (1)` and `copy (2)`,the result is `array1[tid]`=`array2[tid]`=`t1[tid]`.

Only when I remove `extern` the result is what I want (`array1[tid]`=`t1[tid]`,`array2[tid]`=`t2[tid]`).

Can anybody explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
 extern __shared__ T array1[];
 extern __shared__ T array2[];
```

won't work the way you think.

Those pointers (`array1` and `array2`) will point to the same location.

If you want to have multiple arrays using dynamically allocated shared memory, you must follow the instructions given in the [programming guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#shared).  Something like this:

```
 extern __shared__ T array1[];
 T * array2 = array1 + size_of_array_1;
```

should work.

And be sure to pass a size allocation in the kernel launch parameters that is sufficient bytes for both the size of `array1` and the size of `array2`

Comment: Is it possible that both "static __shared__" and "extern __shared__" exist in the same kernel,like:   "__shared__ float array1[N]" and             "extern __shared__ T array2[]"?

Comment: I believe you should be able to use both static and dynamic allocations in the same kernel, did you try it?